# What is the difference between laravel blade components and vue components?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Laravel have blade components that are based on Vue components and you can even use Vue components in Laravel. So what is the difference between both of them? And when you have to use each other i.e. in which case you would prefer Laravel blade component over Vue component and vice versa.

Comment: The difference is that Vue components are evaluated on client side and can react to user actions without reloading the page. If components make use of static data, there's not much practical difference between them except performance and SEO concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Component Based Approach**

[image: Component Based Approach]

[Image credit](https://medium.com/osldev-blog/taking-a-component-based-approach-to-spa-development-d95ea33064bb)

**Blade components**

> The idea of Blade components and slots was inspired by VueJS to build
>   HTML elements into reusable areas.
>
> A component is a reusable group of elements, like you want to create a
>   button and want to reuse it in your application on various places. So
>   we will create a button component and tell Laravel to grab it whenever
>   we want to use it.

[Source](https://www.larashout.com/using-laravel-blade-components-and-slots)

**Vue components**

Building Single Page Apps is quite common these days. Frontend frameworks come with tools and boilerplates that scaffold starter projects which are most of the time **S**ingle **P**age **A**pps.

However, as your application evolves, you add more features and more pages, and consequentially your SPA becomes harder to manage.

> One of the great things about working with Vue is its component-based approach to building user interfaces. This allows you to break your application into smaller, reusable pieces (components) which you can then use to build out a more complicated structure. It just makes everything easier. Each component
>   has its own individual set of JS and CSS that it relies on. They are
>   completely independent.

[Source](https://medium.com/osldev-blog/taking-a-component-based-approach-to-spa-development-d95ea33064bb)

**In which case you would prefer Laravel blade component over Vue component and vice versa ?**

Much of the decision to use blade or vue components will come down to personal taste and the tastes of your development team. Both blade and vue can be used to create robust, well-tested Laravel applications. As long as you are keeping your component' responsibilities focused, you will notice very few practical differences between using blade and vue componenets.

Comment: You can use Vue components in Laravel blade. And you can even use Laravel blade components. So in case of regular multi-page Laravel application, which is better to use. And why? Whats the difference in both of them (in the above context).?